# Empty permalinks settings in .htaccess

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

Permalinks not working other than set to "Default'. I want to change it to `/%postname%.html`, and default `.htaccess` is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But sometimes it becomes …

```
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

… whenever I change the settings of Permalinks. I already change the permission of `.htaccess` to `777` and mod_rewrite is working.  `AllowOverride All` has been set to my working directory. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes it becomes". That seems very weird.

Comment: Yes, sometimes. Whenever I choose a option other than Default then clicked "save changes" at "Permalink Settings", .htacces shows the normal one to me and when I access the page WordPress said "Page not Found". But whenever I choose Default and click "Save Changes", .htacees became a file only with 2 lines "#BEGIN WordPress" and "#END WordPress", and I can access the page normally.

Comment: If I were you I would not set permission of `.htaccess` to `777`. Set this to `666`. Then change permalink structure and see what happens.

Comment: Hi TweetPressFr, I just tried, the result was just the same.

Comment: Then try [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite)